# Combining tables with different columns into single query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm coding a site and I'd like to make a timeline showing the activity of a user: comments he's written (on articles in the site), messages he's posted (on the forums) and [up|down]votes he's cast.

Right now I have three tables (non-relevant fields skipped):

```
COMMENTS
id | author_id | article_id | timestamp

MESSAGES
id | author_id | thread_id | timestamp

VOTES
id | author_id | comment_id | message_id | type | timestamp
```

I'd like to perform a query that, given an `author_id` will return a result combining the `article_id` field from COMMENTS, the `thread_id` from MESSAGES, the `comment_id`, `message_id` and `type` fields from VOTES and the common `timestamp` field, all sorted by the timestamp. The result should be something like this:

```
article_id | thread_id | comment_id | message_id | type | timestamp
```

I'm using PostgreSQL, and so far I've been unable to generate this kind of result.

Could somebody point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**

To clarify what I want to achieve, if I had the following data in the database:

```
COMMENTS
id | author_id | article_id | timestamp
 1 |         1 |         1  | 11:00:10
 2 |         1 |         2  | 11:00:20

MESSAGES
id | author_id | thread_id | timestamp
 3 |         1 |        20 | 12:00:10
 4 |         1 |        21 | 12:00:20

VOTES
id | author_id | comment_id | message_id | type | timestamp
 5 |         1 |          1 |            |    1 | 13:00:10
 6 |         1 |            |          3 |    2 | 13:00:20
```

Then the result should be this:

```
article_id | thread_id | comment_id | message_id | type | timestamp
         1 |           |            |            |      | 11:00:10
         2 |           |            |            |      | 11:00:20
           |        20 |            |            |      | 12:00:10
           |        21 |            |            |      | 12:00:20
           |           |          1 |            |    1 | 13:00:10
           |           |            |          3 |    2 | 13:00:20
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which of the three timestamps do you want to select, or do you want all of them?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I need them all in order to generate the user's timeline. I've updated the original post to illustrate what I'd like to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you need this output, but you can try the following union query:

```
SELECT
    article_id, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, timestamp
FROM COMMENTS
WHERE author_id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    NULL, thread_id, NULL, NULL, NULL, timestamp
FROM MESSAGES
WHERE author_id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    NULL, NULL, comment_id, message_id, type, timestamp
FROM VOTES
WHERE author_id = 1
ORDER BY timestamp
```

Comment: This does produce a full result set, but it doesn't include the common 'timestamp' column.

Comment: @JaviLavandeira Sorry I missed that column.

Answer (score 0):

SOlution

```
select c.author_id ,article_id, thread_id , comment_id, message_id, type, c.timestamp
    FROM COMMENTS c
    LEFT JOIN MESSAGES m
        ON c.author_id = m.author_id and c.timestamp = m.timestamp
    LEFT JOIN VOTES v
        ON c.author_id = v.author_id and c.timestamp = v.timestamp
    where author_id=@author_id
```

if timestamp is not same then try this

```
select c.author_id ,article_id, thread_id , comment_id, message_id, type, isnull(isnull(c.timestamp,m.timestamp),v.timestamp) as timestamp
    FROM COMMENTS c
    full JOIN MESSAGES m
        ON c.author_id = m.author_id 
    full JOIN VOTES v
        ON c.author_id = v.author_id 
    where author_id=@author_id
```

Comment: Hi Ravi. I don't think this will work because the timestamps will never be the same.

Comment: use full join in place of left join and remove checking of timestamp at joins and also use isnull(isnull(c.timestamp,m.timestamp),v.timestamp) in place of c.timestamp in select statement, I think it will help you

Comment: How is it any different from the answer already provided besides it being wrong

Comment: You should elaborate then on _which_ timestamp you want to include.

Comment: I updated my answer please check and reply if it works